# Swift - create array of custom colors

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

Is there a way to create an array of custom colors? I know I can create custom colors in `class UIColors` but in my case I need an array of my custom colors.

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
let listColors: [UIColor] = [
    let color1 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
    let color2 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 2, green: 2, blue: 2, alpha: 1),
    let color3 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 3, green: 3, blue: 3, alpha: 1),
]
```

Comment: what do you mean by custom colors ? subclasses ?

Comment: yes subclasses for `UIColors`

Comment: Surely you can make an array of basically anything you'd like to? Why not? Check out the Swift book or some other basic material if you're unsure how to create arrays.

Comment: Delete the `let colorX = ` parts.

Comment: I know how to create an array :) just not sure how to create an array of custom colors..

Comment: @PhillipMills well that works, but is there a way to name them or would I have to make a real `subclass` for that?

Comment: Reference them by number 0...2.  You *could* name them but then there's not much point to an array.  If you want some kind of structure with names, think dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subclass to create an array do

```
let listColors = [  
    UIColor(displayP3Red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(displayP3Red: 2, green: 2, blue: 2, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(displayP3Red: 3, green: 3, blue: 3, alpha: 1)
]
```

access

```
listColors[index]
```

**or**

```
class Colors {

   static let color1 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
   static let color2 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 2, green: 2, blue: 2, alpha: 1) 
   static let color3 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 3, green: 3, blue: 3, alpha: 1)

}
```

access

```
Colors.color1
```

**or as global**

```
let color1 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
let color2 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 2, green: 2, blue: 2, alpha: 1) 
let color3 = UIColor(displayP3Red: 3, green: 3, blue: 3, alpha: 1)
```

access

```
color1
```

> When you create a color divide by 255

```
UIColor(displayP3Red: 2/255.0, green: 2/255.0, blue: 2/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to be able to reference them by name **or** by array index:

```
let color1 = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), //White
let color2 = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0), //Gray
let color3 = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), //Red

let listColors: [UIColor] = [color1, color2, color3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are supporting dark and light modes in your App, it is best to define your custom colors as assets in your App and then access them something like this

```
extension String {
    static let blueColorName = "Blue"
    static let brownColorName = "Brown"
    static let crustaColorName = "Crusta"
    static let darkRedColorName = "DarkRed"
    static let defaultColorName = "Default"
    static let flamingoColorName = "Tango"
    static let khakiColorName = "Khaki"
    static let greenColorName = "Green"
    static let limeColorName = "Lime"
    static let lustColorName = "Lust"
    static let oliveColorName = "Olive"
    static let orangeColorName = "Orange"
    static let pinkColorName = "Pink"
    static let purpleColorName = "Purple"
    static let roseColorName = "Rose"
    static let redColorName = "Red"
    static let skyColorName = "Sky"
    static let steelColorName = "Steel"
    static let sunColorName = "Sun"
    static let tealColorName = "Teal"
    static let yellowColorName = "Yellow"
    // Tile Background Colors
    static let tileGrayColorName = "TileGray"
    static let tileGreenColorName = "TileGreen"
    static let tileRedColorName = "TileRed"
    static let tileYellowColorName = "TileYellow"
}

extension UIColor {
    
    // MARK: - Custom Color List For Color Picker

    static let customColorsList: [(colorName: String, uiColor: UIColor)] = [
        ("Orange", UIColor(named: .orangeColorName)!),
        ("Tango", UIColor(named: .flamingoColorName)!),
        ("Crusta", UIColor(named: .crustaColorName)!),
        ("Yellow", UIColor(named: .yellowColorName)!),
        ("Sun", UIColor(named: .sunColorName)!),
        ("Khaki", UIColor(named: .khakiColorName)!),
        ("Lime", UIColor(named: .limeColorName)!),
        ("Green", UIColor(named: .greenColorName)!),
        ("Olive", UIColor(named: .oliveColorName)!),
        ("Teal", UIColor(named: .tealColorName)!),
        ("Sky", UIColor(named: .skyColorName)!),
        ("Blue", UIColor(named: .blueColorName)!),
        ("Steel", UIColor(named: .steelColorName)!),
        ("Pink", UIColor(named: .pinkColorName)!),
        ("Rose", UIColor(named: .roseColorName)!),
        ("Purple", UIColor(named: .purpleColorName)!),
        ("Lust", UIColor(named: .lustColorName)!),
        ("Dark Red", UIColor(named: .darkRedColorName)!),
        ("Brown", UIColor(named: .brownColorName)!),
        ("Default", UIColor(named: .defaultColorName)!)
    ]
}
```